# Error as.numeric: weighted average subset works full data set doesn't

Tags: r, subset, weighted-average

I am an R neophyte but this one really has me stumped--I really hope more experienced people can help me out.  I am estimating a simple weighted average.  In my case I have counties numerically coded (FIPS), a soil carbon value, and the area covered by a soil within the county.  Soils of different types and areas occur in a county.  This means a given county may have X1, X2, X3 soil types over Y1, Y2, Y3 areas.  I want to know the overall weighted average soil carbon across a county based on the type of, and area covered, by a given soil.  When I developed some code for a smaller subset of the data (200 rows) a correct value was returned when I compared to hand estimates.  When I applied the code to the full data set (111,000+ rows), I received the error message:

1: In sum(soc[which(soc[, 1] == FIPS[i]), 8]) :
  integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))

I did not receive this error message in the subset.  When I tried the sum(as.numeric(...)) as suggested, I received a different error message.  The weighted averages calculated in the subsetted data were different in the full data set--even for the same county.

Interestingly, when I saved the subsetted data to a different file name, but left the underlying data unchanged, I received the same error message as I did in the full data set.  This makes me think it isn't the code or an as.numeric issue but something to do with the file itself. But I have only been working with R for about a year and know I really don't know.

Thanks in advance!  This the first time I've posted, so I am not sure how to attach data, I'd be happy to send if needed.

My code:

Subsetted data:

```
socT<-read.table("R_SOC8.txt", header=TRUE) 
FIPS<-unique(socT[,1])
WA<-c()


for(i in 1:length(FIPS)){
    WA[i]<-crossprod((socT[which(socT[,1]==FIPS[i]),3]),
    (socT[which(socT[,1]==FIPS[i]),8]))/
    (sum(socT[which(socT[,1]==FIPS[i]),8]))
}


test8<-cbind(FIPS, WA)

print(test8)
```

Full data code:

```
soc<-read.table("R_SOC20.txt", header=TRUE)
FIPS<-unique(soc[,1]) 
WA<-c()


for(i in 1:length(FIPS)){
    WA[i]<-crossprod((soc[which(soc[,1]==FIPS[i]),3]),
    (soc[which(soc[,1]==FIPS[i]),8]))/
    (sum(soc[which(soc[,1]==FIPS[i]),8]))
 }


fipsoc20<-cbind(FIPS, WA)

print(fipsoc20)
```

Sample output:

Subset:

```
     FIPS        WA
[1,] 10001  825.0657
[2,] 10003 1327.9600
[3,] 10005  767.9470
[4,] 10007  731.9469
```

Full data:

```
           FIPS       WA
   [1,]  10001 825.0657
   [2,]  10003       NA
   [3,]  10005       NA
   [4,]  10007 731.9469
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `integer` types and should be using `double`. You can see this easily from the `integer` help page:

`?integer`
Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: doubles can hold much larger integers exactly.

I can't guarantee this since you didn't post the structure of your data. try `typeof()` to confirm.

Comment: when i write typeof(test8) i get "double" back", and typeof(soc20) also gives me back "double". @Alex.

Comment: was correct in that it was a problem related to integers. Although I was already using double as he suggested, when I divided the area by 10,000 to reduce the length, the code worked without issue.  If I hadn't read where he wrote the length is restricted to 10^9, I wouldn't have tried dividing by 10,000.  Many thanks!